# How can I travel without a passport?

Tags: air-travel, passports, international-travel

Say one day my passport is cancelled because I wrote something offensive about my country's president on my Twitter a few years ago. Unfortunately I have only 1 citizenship.

This would probably happen when I'm outside the country. I'm trying to spend most of my time outside the country as a tourist because I see possibility for major instability these years, which would mean extreme oppression and possibly getting stuck in the country for a very long time.

There's a country that's very welcoming (in terms of giving citizenships, not quality of life). They give you a citizenship pretty quickly compared to other ones, though it still takes years. The problem is how am I going to go there without a passport?

It's one of the countries that are very far from other ones. I'd just go live there now but it's difficult to live there and it's not safe. Lots of crime, breaking and entering, kidnapping

PS. I can't afford to spend hundreds of thousands of dollars to buy a passport. I'm open to creative ideas as long as it's relatively safe. Thank you

Comment: "You can guess the country." I can't.

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear and that you may have good reasons for not being specific. *But* unfortunately I don't think this question can be answered if the countries aren't specified. The options available are entirely dependent on which countries you're talking about. "How do I get from Greece to Spain without a passport" is a very different question from "How do I get from Mexico to Canada without a passport", and "How do I get from China to New Zealand without a passport" is entirely different again.

Comment: I'm probably going to be 2000km+ away from the country that gives citizenships easily.

Comment: It seems you are based in the US. Or Russia. Or Saudi Arabia. No, SA does not have a president. Brazil, then? These are the country I can guess.
Well, your best bet is to go to a small country, live there for 10+ years, earn your new citizneship, done.

Comment: I highly doubt US, with the 1st amendment and all.

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) '... you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”'

Comment: "it's difficult to live there and it's not safe" there are countries with short paths to citizenship that have good quality of life

Comment: @AakashM I don't think hypothetical situations are off-topic. It can easily be re-phrased as: "My government cancelled my passport. I'm in such-and-such country. What can I do?", and "My passport will be cancelled in a few months. What steps can I take to avoid getting stuck in an unstable country where I will be persecuted?"

Comment: @user130957 are there precedent of citizens' passports being revoked for political reasons? (In other words, how hypothetical is this?)

Comment: @njzk2 I assume this is similar to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176564/my-government-china-cancelled-my-passport-im-in-malaysia-what-can-i-do , in which case yes, there is precedent (and that might be the country in question). Come to think of it, the circumstances seem rather similar, might be the same asker.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm trying to spend most of my time outside the country because I see possibility for major instability these years, which would mean extreme oppression...

When your passport is cancelled, you can apply for asylum in the country where you are at the time, provided that you have a "well founded fear of persecution" on account of your political beliefs (among other reasons).  Your mentioning  "extreme oppression" suggests that you may have such a fear.  If you are granted asylum, your host country will issue you a refugee travel doucement with which you can travel to other countries.

However, it may be difficult to obtain immigration to a new country once you are s refugee in another country.  The avenues that would be open would mostly be those that are open now, such as immigration on the basis of an employment talent program or similar.

If your ultimate goal is to settle in the "very welcoming" country you mention, then you can try to spend as much time there as possible to maximize the probability that you are there when your passport is cancelled.  Or, if you plan to apply to immigrate with an employment visa, do it now; why wait?

Alternatively, if you *already* have a well founded fear of persecution in your country of citizenship, you can go to the welcoming country with your not-yet-revoked passport and request asylum right away.  It's not a prerequisite that your passport be cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a permanent resident status in the country where you are in right now, then in many cases you can get some kind of international travel document for aliens who can't get a passport from their country of nationality (variously called "alien's passport", "re-entry permit", "[certificate of identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_identity)", etc.). Unfortunately, if you are just in a temporary visitor status, you typically can't get this as it is only for residents.

If you just want to go back to your country of nationality, your country's consulate will typically still issue you a limited travel document for direct return to your country, even if you are not eligible for a regular passport. (And if they don't, well, you can just overstay your status in your current country, and let them arrange with your country of nationality for deportation back to your country of nationality.) Unfortunately, this doesn't help accomplish your goal as once you are back in your country of nationality, you would be unable to travel to the country you wish to immigrate to, without a passport.

Comment: To summarize, you suggest me to already have a permanent residency of a country AND be in this country at the time of my passport is cancelled? because I can be out of the country where I'm a permanent resident, with a cancelled passport, in which case, I'd be stuck there?

Comment: @user130957 I suspect that most countries will also give you an emergency travel document if you're a permanent resident in that country.

Comment: Via the consulate of the country that I'm a a permanent resident of, right? This is true for most countries? Can I ask if you're sure / can someone confirm?

Comment: @user130957 Yes.  I am sure about some countries, for example a US permanent resident never needs a passport to enter the US; a green card is sufficient.

Comment: That would be my suggestion as well: if you fear that the country may revoke your passport and don't want to be stuck there, apply for permanent residence somewhere (Canada, for example, as the citizenship path takes only a few years), and move there permanently.